# Where and what to study - Buddhist compassion and business communication

Tags: lay-buddhism, compassion

I have a background in business studies and communication. I believe that what the Buddha taught about how we should communicate with each other compassionately can change the business world. I want to be able to do a PHD on this topic so that I can spread this concept for the benefit of everyone working in business organisations. However.I have looked at several PHD programs on buddhist studies around the world and most of them ask for bachlor and master in buddhist studies and knowledge of atleast one root language. I do not have any of these. Does anyone know what I can study or where I can explore this idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://tzmvirginia.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/chase-stuart-the-tyranny-of-words-2nd-ed-book-scan.pdf

A popular approach to semantics in which the author discussess how to clarify the meaning of words and achieve more exact communication.

About the Author

Stuart Chase (1888-1985) Born in Somersworth, New Hampshire was an American economist and engineer trained at MIT. His writings covered topics as diverse as general semantics and physical economy. His hybrid background of engineering and economics places him in the same philosophical camp as R. Buckminster Fuller. It has been suggested that he was the originator of the expression a New Deal, which became identified with the economic programs of American president Franklin Delano Roosevelt. He had a cover story in The New Republic entitled "A New Deal for America," during the week that FDR gave his 1932 acceptance speech promising a new deal, but whether FDR speechwriter Samuel Rosenman saw the magazine is not clear.

...
His 1938 book The Tyranny of Words was an early (perhaps the earliest, predating Hayakawa) and influential popularization of Alfred Korzybski's general semantics which can still be read with profit.

Answer (score 2):

You can find info on Buddhist Studies in the USA [here](https://tricycle.org/magazine/where-to-study/) and info on Buddhist Studies in the UK [here](http://ukabs.org.uk/buddhist-studies-in-uk-universities/).

However, it is likely that the kind of research topic that you're considering, would be more acceptable in Business faculties rather than Buddhist Studies faculties. You probably need to find a doctoral supervisor who would be interested.

Searching "Buddhist business workplace" on [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/), I found [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10551-009-0150-9):

> Marques, J. (2010). Toward greater consciousness in the 21st century
>   workplace: How Buddhist practices fit in. *Journal of business ethics*,
>   92(2), 211-225.

Its abstract:

> The purpose of this study was to determine the applicability of
>   Buddhist practices in today’s workplaces. The findings were supported
>   by interviews with Buddhist masters and Buddhist business
>   practitioners, as well as literature review, through phenomenological
>   analysis. As a means of presenting the main reasons why Buddhist
>   practices should be considered in contemporary workplaces, a SWOT
>   analysis is presented. **In this analysis, a number of strengths for
>   using Buddhist practices in workplaces are listed such as
>   pro-scientific, greater personal responsibility, and healthy
>   detachment, while potential weaknesses such as non-harming,
>   equanimity, and no competition are also reviewed.** Both the strengths
>   and the weaknesses could be listed in reverse if applied to a
>   different extent. Among the opportunities were issues such as
>   re-educating the world of business, enhancing personal ownership and a
>   healthier society, while the threats comprised issues such as creating
>   different imbalances, disinterest, and stationary development.

Based on this, I think [Prof. Joan Marques](https://woodbury.edu/faculty/joan-marques/) of Woodbury University's School of Business, might be a good choice for a doctoral supervisor. You can find a list of her other publications on her [Google Scholar profile page](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=duYR4-sAAAAJ&hl=en&oi=sra).

You can search for more relevant papers on [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/), [Scopus](https://www.scopus.com/) or [Web of Knowledge](http://www.webofknowledge.com/), and the authors of those papers may make suitable research supervisors.